# Feature vectors for multiclass perceptron

Tags: python, machine-learning, perceptron

I'm trying to implement Multiclass Perceptron in python. I have fully understood the concept of perceptron algorithm when it comes to multiclassification, but still get puzzled by the feature vectors that we should provide out of training data.

The problem is simply a text (document) classification problem. I'm trying to use unigram term frequencies as features for the perceptron in text preprocessing stage. When I'm constructing features for each document based on term (i.e., unigram) frequencies in each training document, the constructed feature happens to be very sparse (term frequencies for each token that occurs in the document, and 0 for those that do not occur).

My question is about an alternative schema for this. Is there a better solution for constructing feature vectors?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to this is word embedding. In this case instead of encode the words using one-hot vectors, you encode them using dense features like the image below.

This image shows an approach of dimensionality reduction, but the techinique can be used as well as input to the model.

[image]

**Update**

A better approach for text problems are Recurrent Neural Networks (RNN) like LSTM and GRU. These networks, when applied to text problems, predicts the output based on the oder words of the text. The image below shows an example of a RNN.

The 'X' are the input features, X1 is the first word, X2 is the second word and Xt is the last word, and 'W' are the information beeing propagated for the network. Using this schema, the model will make the prediction based on information of all your text, knowing not only the unigrams, but the relationship between the words.

[image]

Comment: I'm quite familiar with word embedding approach, but for this specific problem, I tend to use unigram frequency feature.

Comment: I'm going to update my answer with an approach that I think it's better to your problem, not orly for the input features.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer, but as I said, it's not matter of which approach is better for this problem, but specifically about multi-class perceptron using unigram frequency feature. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I approached this problem by utilizing ID for each unigram that occurs in the training set; specifically, each instance within the training set.

As such, first I create a distinct vocab dictionary by iterating through each document in, giving incremental id to each term that is newly seen. When performing perceptron, I iterate through the vocab ids with their count in the document and multiply them with the associated entry in perceptron weight matrices. In this sense, I would not need to do dot product, ignoring those sparse entries (`0 * 0`).